# How to setup an empty variable that can receive an instance from prepareForSegue?

Tags: swift, xcode, instance, var

I understand the prepareForSegue function, but I'm not sure how to setup an empty variable that can receive an instance.

swift 4 / Xcode 9.2

```
// I want to be able to send classes that look like this to var pickedQuiz

class mathQuestionBank {

var list = [Questions]()

init() {

    let item = Questions(text: "What is two plus two?", correctAnswer: "four", textA: "three", textB: "four", textC: "five", textD: "9y" )

    list.append(item)

    list.append(Questions(text: "How many sides does a triangle have?", correctAnswer: "three", textA: "two", textB: "four", textC: "three", textD: "five"))

    list.append(Questions(text: etc....

    }
}
```

---

```
class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController {

var pickedQuiz = mathQuestionBank() 

// I want to send the entire instance of mathQuestionBank() to var
pickedQuiz. How do I setup the variable pickedQuiz to receive instances 
like mathQuestionBank() ? I'd think it needs to be empty so that it can 
receive the instance from the prepareForSegue() function. 

}
```

Comment: You need a variable on the other end to receive it.  But of course.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon thanks for the response, I do have a variable on the other end. How do I initialize the variable so I can pass instances to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do so, by using the `prepareForSegue()`,

```
let valueToPass = "HelloWorld"
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier" {
            if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NextViewController {
                nextVC.yourVariable = valueToPass
            }
        }
    }
```

in your other class, you can define the variable as follows:

```
class NextViewController {

var yourVariable = ABCType()

}
```

Comment: isn't this just passing the string "HelloWorld" to yourVariable on NextViewController? How can I pass an instance? and how should I setup the variable on NextViewController to receive that instance?

Comment: you can do dat very similarly,

Comment: anyway you can give another example, I understand the prepareForSegue() part, what I'm struggling with is setting an empty variable on NextViewController that can receive an instance

Comment: check again! Now

Comment: I receive the error: Cannot assign value of type 'newInstance' to type 'ABCType'

Comment: OhGod! ABCType() was just for the explanation, use a valid dataType there, check again by removing ABCType() with String(), if you are using String, or anything else but valid.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you mean by "pass an instance." You mean pass an instance of some custom object, not just a value type like a string? Just change yourVariable in @Madhur's example to the desired class type:

```
class ClassToPass {
  value1: String? 
  value2: Data?
  value3: Int
  init(value1: String?, value2: Data?, value3: Int?) {
    self.value1 = value1
    self.value2 = value2
    self.value3 = value3
  }
}

class myViewController: UIViewController {

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier" {
            if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController 
              as? NextViewController {
                let valueToPass = ClassToPass(value1: "A String", 
                                              value2: nil, 
                                              value3: 7)

                nextVC.yourVariable = valueToPass
            }
        }
  }
}

//And in the other view controller:
class NextViewController {
  var yourVariable: ClassToPass? = nil
}
```

Comment: Hey Duncan, thanks for the response. I added more code above to be more clear. But I'm trying to send an entire instance (EXAMPLE ABOVE) mathQuestionBank() to be received by var pickedQuiz. if I write it like: var pickedQuiz = mathQuestionBank() everything works great. But I need to be able to send different instances to var pickedQuiz, i.e: geographyQuestionBank(), scienceQuestionBank(), etc (only one instance would be sent at a time) I hope that cleared up everything. Let me know if you need more info.